# Content script loading in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have problem with developing chrome-extensions.

I have content script:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
   var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;
   if(html){
      chrome.extension.sendRequest({akce: 'content', title: title},function(response){});
      alert(title);
   }
},false);
```

then I have a BG page:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    if(request.akce == 'content'){
        console.log(request.title);
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I start typing to address bar, my content script is loaded on the site which is first in autocomplete list. As you can see in the screenshot below, the content script is loaded before I hit enter in address bar and is loaded on the site where I am not yet.

I have no idea what is happening. Please, please help me.

[screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/fv81o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is injected script from background page.

Example: get referrer from bg page

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{
    code: "chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'content_refer', url: document.referrer},function(response){});"
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    if(request.action == 'content_refer'){
        wipstats.allPages[sender.tab.id].ref = request.url;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have enabled the option called "Instant browsing" in Chrome, I had the same issue some time ago, and exactly because of this reason I disabled that and never used it anymore.

Comment: but this is not useful for me, because I want to distribute my extension to clients, I think that I can't disable "Instant browsing" on client machine :(

Comment: yes, you are right, but I don't like this option of chrome and I believe that this is a question that Google has to solve, because developers can't do anything here. maybe that would be a good to not loading extensions while instant browsing is on and load them after user hits Enter, but again I believe this is what Google has to solve

Comment: and one more thing, I don't know exactly, but maybe there are some chrome-specific DOM events that are possible to catch in this situation and to handle such cases, that would be another good solution...